# Multiplication Table from ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

My task is to make and print a multidimensional array with the shape shown in the attachment.

To accomplish the task, I need to create a StringBuilder and Array list, then print each line in the main method using the for each loop.

Here's where I'm stuck and I don't really know how to move on.

[image]

```
public class MultiplicationTable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (String s : getMultiplicationTable(5)
        ) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

    }
   public static List<String> getMultiplicationTable(int size) {
        ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(String.format("%4s", ""));


        for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
            StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(String.format("%4d", i));

        }
        strings.add(sb.toString());
        for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
            StringBuilder sb3 = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(String.format("%4d", i));

            for (int j = 1; j <= size; j++) {
                sb.append(String.format("%4d", i * j));

            }
            strings.add(sb.toString());
        }
        return strings;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sb2 and sb3 are never used. And you never clear sb.

```
public class MultiplicationTable {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (String s : getMultiplicationTable(5)) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

}
public static List<String> getMultiplicationTable(int size) {
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(String.format("%4s", ""));
    for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
        sb.append(String.format("%4d", i));
    }
    strings.add(sb.toString());

    for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(String.format("%4d", i));
        for (int j = 1; j <= size; j++) {
            sb.append(String.format("%4d", i * j));
        }
        strings.add(sb.toString());
    }
    return strings;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple suggestions.

1. Replace this :

```java
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(String.format("%4s", ""));
```

with this.

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("    "); // four spaces
```

2. Even though you print out the table using `System.out.println()` it would look 
   more like your desired image by appending a "\n" to the StringBuilder of each line.

```
    sb.append("\n");
```

3. Finally, as a convenience, define the format specification as a string.

```java
    String format = "%4d";
```

Then in your print statements, use the format string instead of the actual format.  That reduces the number of locations you have to edit if you want to change the spacing.